# Proof: Succesful matching reduces model dependence

Tags: mathematical-statistics, model, matching, treatment-effect

I am reading through a paper regarding propensity score matching (Gary King and Richard Nielsen. 2019. “Why Propensity Scores Should Not Be Used for Matching.” Political Analysis, 27, 4, Pp. 435-454. Publisher's Version Copy at https://j.mp/2ovYGsW). I am stuck on a proof in section 3.1, and I would greatly appreciate if someone could help med get unstuck.

Setup: $M = \{m_l:\vert m_j(\tilde{x})-m_k(\tilde{x})\vert \leq h, j\neq k \quad and \quad \vert m_l(x)-m_l(y)\vert\leq K_l \cdot d(x,y)\}$, where d(x,y) denotes some measure of distance between x and y and $K_l$ is a Lipschitz constant. Model dependence is then defined as $\vert m_j(x) - m_k(x) \vert$ for two models $m_j,m_k\in M$. Furhtermore we have that $TE_i = Y_i(1) - Y_i(0)$, where $\hat{Y}_i(0)=m_l(T_i=0, X_i)$ for some model $m_l\in M$. $T_i=0$ indicates no treatment and $T_i=1$ indicates treatment. $X_{j(i)}$ denotes the closest unit in the opposite treatment group, where $j(i)=arg min_{j\vert T_j=1-T_i}d(X_i,X_j)$. Imbalance is denoted by $I(X)=mean_{i\in{\{i\}}}d(X_i,X_{j(i)})$. For a matched subset, $\tilde{X}$, we then have $I(\tilde{X})<I(X)$. $\hat{TE}_i(m_l)$ denotes an estimate of $TE_i$ found under model $m_l$. The mean operator used troughout is the sample mean. The paper goes into much greater detail on the setup, this is just a short recap.

The proof I am having trouble with then goes likes this:

$\vert \hat{\tau}(m_j)-\hat{\tau}(m_k) \vert = mean_{i\in\{i\}} \vert\hat{TE}_i(m_j)-\hat{TE}_i(m_k)\vert \leq mean_{i\in\{i\}}\vert m_j(X_i)-m_k(X_i) \vert = mean_{i\in\{i\}}\vert[m_j(X_i)-m_j(X_{j(i)})]+[m_k(X_i)-m_k(X_{j(i)})]+[m_j(X_{j(i)})-m_k(X_{j(i)})]\vert\leq mean_{i\in\{i\}}[\vert m_j(X_i)-m_j(X_{j(i)})\vert+\vert m_k(X_i)-m_k(X_{j(i)})\vert+\vert m_j(X_{j(i)})-m_k(X_{j(i)})\vert]\leq (K_j+K_k)d(X_i,X_{j(i)})+h$

Now according to the paper, this implies that:
$\vert \hat{\tau}(m_j)-\hat{\tau}(m_k) \vert \leq I(\tilde{X})<I(X)$, which I don't quite see how.

Furthermore I don't really understand how they arrive at the first "$\leq$" nor the second "=" in the derivation above.

Thank you for taking the time to read this, any input or ideas on how to proceed are more than welcome!